# Decrypting an encrypted text file generated using PL/SQL, encryption type AES256/CBC/PKCS5

Tags: encryption

I generated a text file, obtaining data from columns in a table.  I have then encrypted that data using PL/SQL and encryption type of AES256/CBC/PKCS5.

I now need a program for the end user to use to decrypt that text file without needing to have oracle installed.  (I know the solution of how to do it in Oracle, but the end user would not have Oracle installed)

So if you know of a good program, please post.

Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Export to an accessible format before you encrypt.

Comment: I don't think format is really the issue.  The problem is that most decrypting programs/tools are created to decrypt only the files encrypted by their own program.

Comment: Surely 1. export from Oracle to CSV; 2. encrypt; 3. send; 4. they decrypt; 5. they use the CSV.

Comment: Yes that method would be easy to do.  Just output data into a text file, encrypt it using AxCrypt or WinZip and send it, they decrypt using the password, and use the CSV.

But my issue is, I want to output encrypted data.  I want to combine step 1 and 2. To have more efficiency and less manual work.